# send mail with a value of a selection outside the form itself

Tags: php, forms, email

I want to send the value of a selection outside the form itself when submitted.

for example:

```
<select>
    <option name="iPhone"> iPhone </option>
    <option name="Android"> Android </option>
</select>

<form >
    <input name="username" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verstuur" />
</form>
```

The value of the select box above wont get send when the form is submitted, but how can I do this?

Comment: Why can't it be included in the form? You cannot submit a value that is not within the form, so you have to either put the selected value in a hidden input on submit, or just put the select box inside the form tags.

Comment: Submit form using ajax read select box value using jquery

Comment: @AndroidGears ok and how do I do that

Comment: How about [documenting yourself](https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=submit+form+using+ajax+example)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="select">
    <option name="iPhone"> iPhone </option>
    <option name="Android"> Android </option>
</select>

<form >
    <input name="username" id="name" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verstuur" class="submitcancel" />
</form>

$(function() {
    $(".submitcancel").click(function () {


        var = $("#select").val();
     var name = $("#name").val();


        //if(id>0)
        var dataString = 'select=' + escape(select)+'name='+escape(name);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "target.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(html) {

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you please give a little explanation?

Comment: do you know jquery and ajax. add jquery library in our file in head section below that in <script > tag and above code also mention the classes and id to your html